# Get message response from postgresql using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I wanna ask about how to get message response from PostgreSQL when we execute a query.

Message response from PostgreSQL what I mean are like this, for example:

- Query returned successfully: 1 row affected, 11 ms execution time.
- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_grouptab"
- etc.

I am using JDBC.

I have tried to get it from `executeUpdate()` from Statement class. but it's only return int that representing whether the query executed successfully or not.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you get statements like

> Query returned successfully: 1 row affected, 11 ms execution time.

but you have alternative to use like [`statement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) which returns the the no of rows that have been affected by the execution of the DML statement.

Coming to the other statement

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_grouptab"

Whenever an error has occurred in the database, a `SQLException` is thrown, you need to explicitly catch the exception and handle it. [SQLException Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29) in addition, please check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm) where it briefly describes exception handling in JDBC.

If you want to check if there were any warnings after you execute a query you can use [`getWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings%28%29) and use methods like `getMessage()` to get the message of the warning.

Below is a skeleton

```
 try {
     // execute sql statements here
     log.info(statement.getWarnings().getMessage());
 }
 catch(SQLException ex) {
     // an exception has occurred get all info related to the exception
     log.info(ex.getErrorCode());
     log.info(ex.getMessage());
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally {
     // close all open connections
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank a lot, Patton.
I'll use SQLExcetion for any error message response in my app and executeUpdate() to get the number of rows that have been affected by the execution.

Comment: You are welcome! If you come across any issues just let me know!

Comment: @ilyasfals: It is suggested to accpe the helpful answer.